# MySQL ignoring my.cnf

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I've just set some innodb settings in my.cnf and restarted the server but they haven't taken effect.

What's the correct way to do this?

I did:

`sudo vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

saved the file, and then ran `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without knowing more details of what you changed, and assuming your mysql reads the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file fine (I don't know Ubuntu), the only thing I can think of is where you placed the innodb settings.
Are the settings in the [mysqld] group?

According to the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-configuration.html) : "You can place InnoDB options in the [mysqld] group of any option file that your server reads when it starts."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is what should be done normally!

Did you check the result of the second command `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`? It can fail sometimes. You can confirm this by listing the pid value of mysql process before and after restarting it.

```
$ ps -ef | grep mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this information in the MySQL reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html

It explains where MySQL looks for your cnf file. Use this info to confirm that MySQL is using the cnf file you think it is.