# Why MySQL doesn't use settings specified in my.cnf?

Tags: linux, mysql

I've installed MySQL 5.5.15 on debian-lenny server. I used default instruction & settings to install it.
Now, my server starts successfully, but seem non of my specified settings in /etc/my.cnf take effect(e.g. collation-server or des-key-file parameters) but when I enter an invalid setting, my server fails at startup(seems that some settings like base_dir or data_dir take effect correctly).
This is my startup script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Copyright Abandoned 1996 TCX DataKonsult AB & Monty Program KB & Detron HB
# This file is public domain and comes with NO WARRANTY of any kind

# MySQL daemon start/stop script.

# Usually this is put in /etc/init.d (at least on machines SYSV R4 based
# systems) and linked to /etc/rc3.d/S99mysql and /etc/rc0.d/K01mysql.
# When this is done the mysql server will be started when the machine is
# started and shut down when the systems goes down.

# Comments to support chkconfig on RedHat Linux
# chkconfig: 2345 64 36
# description: A very fast and reliable SQL database engine.

# Comments to support LSB init script conventions
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: mysql
# Required-Start: $local_fs $network $remote_fs
# Should-Start: ypbind nscd ldap ntpd xntpd
# Required-Stop: $local_fs $network $remote_fs
# Default-Start:  2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: start and stop MySQL
# Description: MySQL is a very fast and reliable SQL database engine.
### END INIT INFO

# If you install MySQL on some other places than /usr/local/mysql, then you
# have to do one of the following things for this script to work:
#
# - Run this script from within the MySQL installation directory
# - Create a /etc/my.cnf file with the following information:
#   [mysqld]
#   basedir=<path-to-mysql-installation-directory>
# - Add the above to any other configuration file (for example ~/.my.ini)
#   and copy my_print_defaults to /usr/bin
# - Add the path to the mysql-installation-directory to the basedir variable
#   below.
#
# If you want to affect other MySQL variables, you should make your changes
# in the /etc/my.cnf, ~/.my.cnf or other MySQL configuration files.

# If you change base dir, you must also change datadir. These may get
# overwritten by settings in the MySQL configuration files.

basedir=
datadir=

# Default value, in seconds, afterwhich the script should timeout waiting
# for server start. 
# Value here is overriden by value in my.cnf. 
# 0 means don't wait at all
# Negative numbers mean to wait indefinitely
service_startup_timeout=900

# Lock directory for RedHat / SuSE.
lockdir='/var/lock/subsys'
lock_file_path="$lockdir/mysql"

# The following variables are only set for letting mysql.server find things.

# Set some defaults
mysqld_pid_file_path=
if test -z "$basedir"
then
  basedir=/usr/local/mysql
  bindir=/usr/local/mysql/bin
  if test -z "$datadir"
  then
    datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data
  fi
  sbindir=/usr/local/mysql/bin
  libexecdir=/usr/local/mysql/bin
else
  bindir="$basedir/bin"
  if test -z "$datadir"
  then
    datadir="$basedir/data"
  fi
  sbindir="$basedir/sbin"
  libexecdir="$basedir/libexec"
fi

# datadir_set is used to determine if datadir was set (and so should be
# *not* set inside of the --basedir= handler.)
datadir_set=

#
# Use LSB init script functions for printing messages, if possible
#
lsb_functions="/lib/lsb/init-functions"
if test -f $lsb_functions ; then
  . $lsb_functions
else
  log_success_msg()
  {
    echo " SUCCESS! $@"
  }
  log_failure_msg()
  {
    echo " ERROR! $@"
  }
fi

PATH="/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:$basedir/bin"
export PATH

mode=$1    # start or stop

[ $# -ge 1 ] && shift


other_args="$*"   # uncommon, but needed when called from an RPM upgrade action
           # Expected: "--skip-networking --skip-grant-tables"
           # They are not checked here, intentionally, as it is the resposibility
           # of the "spec" file author to give correct arguments only.

case `echo "testing\c"`,`echo -n testing` in
    *c*,-n*) echo_n=   echo_c=     ;;
    *c*,*)   echo_n=-n echo_c=     ;;
    *)       echo_n=   echo_c='\c' ;;
esac

parse_server_arguments() {
  for arg do
    case "$arg" in
      --basedir=*)  basedir=`echo "$arg" | sed -e 's/^[^=]*=//'`
                    bindir="$basedir/bin"
            if test -z "$datadir_set"; then
              datadir="$basedir/data"
            fi
            sbindir="$basedir/sbin"
            libexecdir="$basedir/libexec"
        ;;
      --datadir=*)  datadir=`echo "$arg" | sed -e 's/^[^=]*=//'`
            datadir_set=1
    ;;
      --pid-file=*) mysqld_pid_file_path=`echo "$arg" | sed -e 's/^[^=]*=//'` ;;
      --service-startup-timeout=*) service_startup_timeout=`echo "$arg" | sed -e 's/^[^=]*=//'` ;;
    esac
  done
}

wait_for_pid () {
  verb="$1"           # created | removed
  pid="$2"            # process ID of the program operating on the pid-file
  pid_file_path="$3" # path to the PID file.

  i=0
  avoid_race_condition="by checking again"

  while test $i -ne $service_startup_timeout ; do

    case "$verb" in
      'created')
        # wait for a PID-file to pop into existence.
        test -s "$pid_file_path" && i='' && break
        ;;
      'removed')
        # wait for this PID-file to disappear
        test ! -s "$pid_file_path" && i='' && break
        ;;
      *)
        echo "wait_for_pid () usage: wait_for_pid created|removed pid pid_file_path"
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac

    # if server isn't running, then pid-file will never be updated
    if test -n "$pid"; then
      if kill -0 "$pid" 2>/dev/null; then
        :  # the server still runs
      else
        # The server may have exited between the last pid-file check and now.  
        if test -n "$avoid_race_condition"; then
          avoid_race_condition=""
          continue  # Check again.
        fi

        # there's nothing that will affect the file.
        log_failure_msg "The server quit without updating PID file ($pid_file_path)."
        return 1  # not waiting any more.
      fi
    fi

    echo $echo_n ".$echo_c"
    i=`expr $i + 1`
    sleep 1

  done

  if test -z "$i" ; then
    log_success_msg
    return 0
  else
    log_failure_msg
    return 1
  fi
}

# Get arguments from the my.cnf file,
# the only group, which is read from now on is [mysqld]
if test -x ./bin/my_print_defaults
then
  print_defaults="./bin/my_print_defaults"
elif test -x $bindir/my_print_defaults
then
  print_defaults="$bindir/my_print_defaults"
elif test -x $bindir/mysql_print_defaults
then
  print_defaults="$bindir/mysql_print_defaults"
else
  # Try to find basedir in /etc/my.cnf
  conf=/etc/my.cnf
  print_defaults=
  if test -r $conf
  then
    subpat='^[^=]*basedir[^=]*=\(.*\)$'
    dirs=`sed -e "/$subpat/!d" -e 's//\1/' $conf`
    for d in $dirs
    do
      d=`echo $d | sed -e 's/[  ]//g'`
      if test -x "$d/bin/my_print_defaults"
      then
        print_defaults="$d/bin/my_print_defaults"
        break
      fi
      if test -x "$d/bin/mysql_print_defaults"
      then
        print_defaults="$d/bin/mysql_print_defaults"
        break
      fi
    done
  fi

  # Hope it's in the PATH ... but I doubt it
  test -z "$print_defaults" && print_defaults="my_print_defaults"
fi

#
# Read defaults file from 'basedir'.   If there is no defaults file there
# check if it's in the old (depricated) place (datadir) and read it from there
#

extra_args=""
if test -r "$basedir/my.cnf"
then
  extra_args="-e $basedir/my.cnf"
else
  if test -r "$datadir/my.cnf"
  then
    extra_args="-e $datadir/my.cnf"
  fi
fi

parse_server_arguments `$print_defaults $extra_args mysqld server mysql_server mysql.server`

#
# Set pid file if not given
#
if test -z "$mysqld_pid_file_path"
then
  mysqld_pid_file_path=$datadir/`hostname`.pid
else
  case "$mysqld_pid_file_path" in
    /* ) ;;
    * )  mysqld_pid_file_path="$datadir/$mysqld_pid_file_path" ;;
  esac
fi

case "$mode" in
  'start')
    # Start daemon

    # Safeguard (relative paths, core dumps..)
    cd $basedir

    echo $echo_n "Starting MySQL"
    if test -x $bindir/mysqld_safe
    then
      # Give extra arguments to mysqld with the my.cnf file. This script
      # may be overwritten at next upgrade.
      $bindir/mysqld_safe --defaults-file="/etc/my.cnf" --datadir="$datadir" --pid-file="$mysqld_pid_file_path" $other_args >/dev/null 2>&1 &
      wait_for_pid created "$!" "$mysqld_pid_file_path"; return_value=$?

      # Make lock for RedHat / SuSE
      if test -w "$lockdir"
      then
        touch "$lock_file_path"
      fi

      exit $return_value
    else
      log_failure_msg "Couldn't find MySQL server ($bindir/mysqld_safe)"
    fi
    ;;

  'stop')
    # Stop daemon. We use a signal here to avoid having to know the
    # root password.

    if test -s "$mysqld_pid_file_path"
    then
      mysqld_pid=`cat "$mysqld_pid_file_path"`

      if (kill -0 $mysqld_pid 2>/dev/null)
      then
        echo $echo_n "Shutting down MySQL"
        kill $mysqld_pid
        # mysqld should remove the pid file when it exits, so wait for it.
        wait_for_pid removed "$mysqld_pid" "$mysqld_pid_file_path"; return_value=$?
      else
        log_failure_msg "MySQL server process #$mysqld_pid is not running!"
        rm "$mysqld_pid_file_path"
      fi

      # Delete lock for RedHat / SuSE
      if test -f "$lock_file_path"
      then
        rm -f "$lock_file_path"
      fi
      exit $return_value
    else
      log_failure_msg "MySQL server PID file could not be found!"
    fi
    ;;

  'restart')
    # Stop the service and regardless of whether it was
    # running or not, start it again.
    if $0 stop  $other_args; then
      $0 start $other_args
    else
      log_failure_msg "Failed to stop running server, so refusing to try to start."
      exit 1
    fi
    ;;

  'reload'|'force-reload')
    if test -s "$mysqld_pid_file_path" ; then
      read mysqld_pid <  "$mysqld_pid_file_path"
      kill -HUP $mysqld_pid && log_success_msg "Reloading service MySQL"
      touch "$mysqld_pid_file_path"
    else
      log_failure_msg "MySQL PID file could not be found!"
      exit 1
    fi
    ;;
  'status')
    # First, check to see if pid file exists
    if test -s "$mysqld_pid_file_path" ; then 
      read mysqld_pid < "$mysqld_pid_file_path"
      if kill -0 $mysqld_pid 2>/dev/null ; then 
        log_success_msg "MySQL running ($mysqld_pid)"
        exit 0
      else
        log_failure_msg "MySQL is not running, but PID file exists"
        exit 1
      fi
    else
      # Try to find appropriate mysqld process
      mysqld_pid=`pidof $libexecdir/mysqld`
      if test -z $mysqld_pid ; then 
        if test -f "$lock_file_path" ; then 
          log_failure_msg "MySQL is not running, but lock file ($lock_file_path) exists"
          exit 2
        fi 
        log_failure_msg "MySQL is not running"
        exit 3
      else
        log_failure_msg "MySQL is running but PID file could not be found"
        exit 4
      fi
    fi
    ;;
    *)
      # usage
      basename=`basename "$0"`
      echo "Usage: $basename  {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status}  [ MySQL server options ]"
      exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem after I upgraded to MySQL 5.5.14, my query cache and innodb buffer pool settings would not take effect on the server, but everything I checked on the server showed that the config file was being loaded, just found the solution here:

[MySQL ignoring my.cnf](https://serverfault.com/questions/212016/mysql-ignoring-my-cnf)

Seems that grouping items in [square brackets] are actually commands and not comments, make sure to put your MySQL config options under the [mysqld] group, and don't make your own up like I did to group your config settings, use # at the beginning of the line to comment.

Use: `mysql --print-defaults` after restarting to see that your settings have taken effect.

Hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 4):

If you installed it through apt-get then, the last my.cnf read is in */etc/mysql/my.cnf*. The one you showed us (*/etc/my.cnf*) is read first, but it's overwritten later by */etc/mysql/my.cnf* . So, if you put some directive causing troubles, will be found first, but if you write some other, maybe overwritten later.

You can also use `--print-defaults` options to get the default options that were loaded. Check this page too: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html

EDIT:

Sorry, I think confused things a little bit. My English is not good. Just try to do what you wanted to do in */etc/mysql/my.cnf*

Comment: I've installed mysql using binary distribution available on mysql website. & I've NOT /etc/mysql/ directory on my server!

Comment: uhm, try modifying some common variable, like innodb_buffer_pool_size and use --print-defaults to see if it's changing.

Comment: yes, seems that my variables are loaded, but they doesn't work! for example changing in des_key_file has no effect on result of DES_ENCRYPT function

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck with this problem for about a day in my case, on Ubuntu 18.04, MySQL 5.6 was not following symlinks. (Why I don't really know).

So ensure that your `my.cnf` file is not a symlink. To check this, you can use `ls -al`, here is some sample output

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    24 Oct  3  2017 my.cnf -> /etc/alternatives/my.cnf
```

It should look like:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1028 Feb 15 14:43 my.cnf
```

In my environment, I had
`/etc/mysql/my.cnf` which was symlinked to, `/etc/alternatives/my.cnf`, which was then symlinked to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback`

So I ran the following commands in `/etc/mysql/`:

```sh
sudo mv my.cnf my.cnf.bak
sudo cp my.cnf.fallback my.cnf
```

**Note**: If you use this workaround, upgrading mysql via `apt get` may fail because it expects `my.cnf.fallback` file to exists. To fix this, I used a symlink to point `my.cnf.fallback` to point to the main config file. e.g:

```
sudo ln -s my.cnf my.cnf.fallback
```

Comment: Turns out my `my.cnf` is also symlinked to `/etc/alternatives/my.cnf`, using mysql-server from apt on Ubuntu 18.04. I guess this is the default? Doesn't seem like it should be.

Comment: Yah my installation was from apt as well, though it's been installed for awhile... likely when I was still running Ubuntu 16, so I wasn't sure. But this is something I wouldn't have done myself, so likely the default.

Comment: I had the same problem. `my.cnf` was symlinked to `/etc/alternatives/my.cnf`. removed the symlinked and copy the `my.cnf.fallback` to `my.cnf`. Working fine now. Thanks